# Android studio gradle task list not build issue

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, android-studio

I was doing a project on kotlin in android studio. While connecting to firebase, I was going to get the SHA code and write it, but I could not get the SHA code, although they said to turn off a setting on the Internet, it did not work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkPmp.png)

I enabled this setting
("Configure all Gradle tasks during Gradle Sync (this can make Gradle Sync slower)").
I synced the project again but none of them worked. The list in the photo I want from you
I want it back to normal.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0Tt7.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of android studio, to get SHA-1, SHA-256 need to do that.

```
    Step 1 : Go to Gradle
    Step 2 : Click on Execute Gradle Task
    Step 3 : Write signingreport (write carefully and same) press Enter
    Step 4 : wait... in console, signing report generated. after that Copy SHA-1, SHA-256 and paste at firebase.
```

see in this picture here. [image]